# I'm using HTML5 Local storage to make save games for users. It just is not working. (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html

This is the [tutorial](http://blog.samgb.com/incrementals-from-zero-to-hero-part-3/) I have been using. 
It's right at the very bottom.

The functions i'm using are:

```
function saveGame(){
    printMessageLine("Saved.");
    localStorage['shittyInc_save'] = btoa(JSON.stringify(game));
}

function loadGame() {

    var save_data = get_cookie('shittyInc_save');
    printMessageLine("Loaded.");
    console.log(save_data);
    if (!save_data) return;
    console.log(save_data);
    game = save_data
}
```

the variable game looks like

```
    var game = {
     money: 0,
     xp: 0,
     level: 1,
     xpPimps: 0,
     slaves: 0,
     printers: 0,
     xpWhores: 0,
     slaveDrivers: 0,
     xpMines: 0,
     moneyTrees: 0,
     shittyInvestors: 0,
     shitMoney: 0,
     shittyCompanies: 0,
     moneyPigs: 0,
     shittyBitcoins: 0
};
```

the variable is used correctly and has been tested.

I have a button that uses `saveGame();` and `loadGame();`

```
<p><button onclick="saveGame()" style="background: #ccc url(triangular.png); padding: 0.2em 2em"">Save</button></p>
     <p><button onclick="loadGame()" style="background: #ccc url(triangular.png); padding: 0.2em 2em"">Load</button></p>
```

nothing seems to do anything, what am I missing?

Got It, fixed code below:

```
  function loadGame() {

    var save_data = localStorage['shittyInc_save']
    printMessageLine("Loaded.");
    console.log(save_data);
    if (!save_data) return;
    console.log(save_data);

    game = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['shittyInc_save']))
}
```

Comment: where is get_cookie() ?

Comment: `get_cookie('shittyInc_save')` should be changed to `localStorage['shittyInc_save']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tutorial correctly uses the `localStorage[]` object for both saving and loading.

About 2/3 through http://blog.samgb.com/incrementals-from-zero-to-hero-part-3/

> We interface with local storage like this:
>
> Saving
>
> `localStorage['clickclick_save'] = btoa(JSON.stringify(player));`
>
> Loading
>
> `player = JSON.parse(atob(localStorage['clickclick_save']))`

The code you posted mismatches two different ways of storing and loading game data that are taught in the tutorial.  It is as though you left your wallet under the bed and then looked for it in a drawer.

Comment: Whoops! well your advice got me to look under the bed! thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You get the data from localStorage the same way you stored it there, not with `get_cookie`.

```
var data = 'some data';
//save to localStorage
localStorage['myData'] = data;

//get from localStorage
var fromStorage = localStorage['myData']; //'some data'
```

Side note: inline javascript is bad practice and will cause you troubles. Read these results: https://www.google.com/search?q=Why+is+inline+js+bad%3F It is best practice to attach the event listener with `addEventListener`, like this:

**Markup:**

```
<button id="myButton"></button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var myButton = document.getElementById('myButton');
myButton.addEventListener('click', myClickFunction);

myClickFunction(event) {
  //do something
}
```

Here's a complete example demonstrating click functions with saving and loading from `localStorage`. Try it out by typing into the input and click "save". You can then change the input or reload the page and get the value back by clicking "load". **[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/IjAZUGOS/1/edit)**

**Markup:**

```
<input id="save-data" type="text" placeholder="type data here">
<button id="save">Save</button>
<button id="load">Load</button>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
var save = document.getElementById('save');
var load = document.getElementById('load');
var saveDataInput = document.getElementById('save-data');

save.addEventListener('click', function() {
  saveGame();
});

load.addEventListener('click', function() {
  loadGame();
});

function saveGame() {
  localStorage.saveData = saveDataInput.value;
}

function loadGame() {
  saveDataInput.value = localStorage.saveData;
}
```

Comment: i'd be glad to focus on this inline thing but my first problem is not resolved. I'm pretty sure i did this wrong. I changed the coding to 'function loadGame() {
  
    var data = 'shittyInc_save';
    localStorage['shittyInc_save'] = data;
    var fromStorage = localStorage['shittyInc_save'];
}' That looks like posh so i'll post it in my question.

Comment: @RykerWells don't just copy and paste code. My code was a demonstration of the issue...it makes absolutely no sense to use it like you did. Learn from my answer - don't just copy.

Comment: @RykerWells You were meant to change this line `var save_data = get_cookie('shittyInc_save');` to `var save_data = localStorage['shittyInc_save'];` Also...I'm not a fan of the needless profanity.

Comment: i'm trying! i didn't understand your explanation, nor did i copy and paste.

Comment: I very much appreciate your help, my game is called the "shitty incremental game" it's a joke. I'm also not trying to impress you i'm just a guy trying to learn how to program Javascript. So if you still want to help, lets focus on the issue at hand. I changed the line like you said but I still get nothing, i edited it in the question to show what it is now.

Comment: @RykerWells You seem a bit apprehensive. If I weren't trying to help, I wouldn't be trying to help :)  Maybe my updated answer will help.

Comment: This is a fine answer as well, +1